# WebRTC : gclient runhooks not working

Tags: android, webrtc, boringssl

Steps I followed to build WebRTC for Android in UBUNTU 13.10 env.

Check out the code:

```
gclient config https://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
echo "target_os = ['android', 'unix']" >> .gclient
gclient sync --nohooks
cd trunk
source ./build/android/envsetup.sh
export GYP_DEFINES="build_with_libjingle=1 build_with_chromium=0 libjingle_java=1 OS=android $GYP_DEFINES"
gclient runhooks
```

I'm getting this error:

```
gyp: /home/joss/Desarrollo/Glass/GDK/librerias/webrtc/trunk/third_party/boringssl/boringssl.gyp not found (cwd: /home/joss/Desarrollo/Glass/GDK/librerias/webrtc)
Error: Command /usr/bin/python trunk/webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc -Dextra_gyp_flag=0 returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/joss/Desarrollo/Glass/GDK/librerias/webrtc
```

If I remove `"OS=android"` from `GYP_DEFINES` the command "gclient runhooks" works but if I try to use the generated library `"libjingle_peerconnection_so.so"` after ninja build I get the following error in Android:

```
dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.mundoglass.glassrtc-1/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so") failed: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/com.mundoglass.glassrtc-1/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so" not 32-bit: 2
```

Please, let me know if I'm doing any step wrong. I'm not sure if I have to use `"OS=android"` to generated the Android libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong.

your error is mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=3622) and i guess it will be fixed.

```
"Yes, chrome has moved to BoringSSL from OpenSSL, which causes some problems in WebRTC Android. We are looking into it."
```

You can try an older revision, I tried revision r6783 as suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=3641) and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [example](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/), i have tried it and work success fully.

Only need to make one change is the link provided in this example for gclient config command is older one. Follow your link gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

Also make sure that you have oracle jdk-6, other version creates issues while following the steps to get the native code
Good luck.